# RevealJS transitions in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, reveal.js

Ive added [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/) to my rails 7 app and with a little tinkering I can switch between slides, however the transitions (eg, *slide* or *fade*) do not work.

In terms of installation:

```
yarn add reveal.js
```

application.js

```js
import Reveal from 'reveal.js';
import Markdown from 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm.js';

let deck = new Reveal({
   plugins: [ Markdown ]
})
deck.initialize();
```

slides html:

```html
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="slides">
    <section data-transition="slide"><h1>Horizontal 1</h1></section>
    <section data-transition="fade"><h1>Horizontal 2</h1></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

### What I have done/tried

I dont have any javascript errors in my console so im thinking this might just some issue with the css / the way im importing the css. so far I have tried copying the reveal.scss content (from node_modules) into a file in my *assets/stylesheets/reveal.scss* with no luck:

```bash
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
12:31:02 js.1   | You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
12:31:02 js.1   | > @use "sass:math";
```

I also tried commenting out the lines (only 3) that use the *math* property, however that didnt work for me.

I tried importing the css direction (in *assets/stylesheets/application.scss*) with:

```css
@import "reveal.js/dist/reveal"
// and 
@import "reveal.js/css/reveal"
```

the file in *dist* is a *.css* file, while the other one has the contents that I copied before and showed the same error regarding **sass:math**.

Next I thought I might not have **sass** so I did `yarn add sass` and `yarn add node-sass`, which also didnt make the transitions work.

Now when I open the *demo.html* and *index.html* files (that come with the reveal.js dependency in the node_modules) in a browser tab transitions work seamlessly. Meaning it must have to do with how im importing the css/scss?

EDIT: webpack.config.js

```
const path    = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: {
    application: "./app/javascript/application.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/assets/builds"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your webpack config, etc? Sounds like there might be an issue there.

Comment: added the webpack.config.js
need to see anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install and then add the appropriate loaders to your webpack config. [Here is the official webpack documentation.](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) It would look something like this:

```
const path    = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: {
    application: "./app/javascript/application.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/assets/builds"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: alright, i followed the docs and then added (manually) the **module** part but it still wont budge. for clarity i added all three loaders: **sass-loader**, **style-loader** and **css-loader** with **yarn**